# Why doesn't Wordpress assign <html id="ei9"... for Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm accustomed to Wordpress automagically adding an IE specific ID attribute to the HTML tag for writing internet explorer-specific css classes. I just noticed that this feature isn't currently working when I view the site in IE9.

In IE8...

```
<html id="ie8" lang="en-US">
```

In IE9...

```
<html lang="en-US">
```

Is this the intended behavior?
Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: it would be more useful for all if you just posted directly what's the bug you have in IE9 :-)

Comment: I'm pleased that you want to help, but that's a very different question.

Comment: Allow me, if you don't know how to find where the html conditionals are in your theme then I don't think you'll have lots of chance in resolving any bugs for IE9 :-)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm perfectly fine. See my comment under MarcoK's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this has been defined in your Wordpress theme:

```
<!--[if IE 6]> <html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)]><!--> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
```

These [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will be read by IE, and will add the ID to the HTML. This could be for loading some CSS, or something specific for only that version of IE.

If you want, you could write this:

```
<!--[if IE 9]> <html id="ie9"> <![endif]-->
```

And add some IE9 specific stuff inside that.

Comment: Make sense. I'll have a look.

Comment: Bingo! It WAS theme-specific. For some reason I assumed that feature was added by the WP core via a filter or something. Not sure why I jumped to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because IE8 and before all had weird quirks that required hacks to get around, IE9 is relatively decent, so it's probably unneeded to add extra definitions for it.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. It's too bad if it's true because IE9 is certainly not without it's quirks.

Comment: @Emerson, you might have a look at Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/) to help deal with browser incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because IE9 is considered a milestone that fixes a lot of the issues that plagued WordPress in the past.

If you still want this sort of functionality, why not use conditional comments like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Much nicer right? This would go into `header.php` of your theme of course.

Hope that helps,
Mikey.